# Adobe flex copy paste htmlText into a text area

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4, flex3

I've a textArea1, i'm copying htmlText from a different textArea2 to the current text area, it bring the formatting of the textArea2, that is ok, when I clear the textArea1 text, when I start typing, i still get the same format of the textArea2, how do i know what was pasted into the textArea? I've tried paste event, it did not trigger any thing.

What i'm trying to acheive is, try to find out what was pasted here, if the style of the text that is pasted is different, then try to update the styles to the original. How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reset the htmlText property of the control. This has done the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to check the current style of the textfield you could simply use

```
textfield.getTextFormat()
```

and then compare it to your initial one. And if you want to check on paste, try using the `Event.CHANGE` event.

Comment: I had to reset the htmlText property of the control. This has done the trick. Thanks.